# VLookup of a VLookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

All the single use VLOOKUP formulas work perfectly, but the formula below is a nested VLOOKUP and always fails.

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(V2,PRAISe,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(D2,PRAISe,2,FALSE),Progress,2,FALSE)
```

When I step thought the formula the nested VLOOKUPS work fine and resolve to the correct decimal value. When the top level vlookup searches for that decimal value I always get a no value found error.

The lookup ranges are as follows:

```
  PRAISE Lookup
    1-  1.20
    1+  1.80
    1=  1.50
    2-  2.20
    2+  2.80
    2=  2.50
    etc. etc.


   Grade Lookup
    1.20    1-
    1.50    1=
    1.80    1+
    2.20    2-
    2.50    2=
    2.80    2+
    etc. etc.

    Progress    
    0.00    0
    0.30    1
    0.60    2
    0.90    3
    1.20    4
    etc. etc.
```

Things I have tried.

At first I thought it was due to the decimal places and an exact match problem, so I multiplied all my results by 10, so I was only working with whole numbers. Unfortunately I got the same result.

I have also tried spitting the formula across two columns. Again the subtraction works and resolves to a decimal number. However when I then try and look that number up as a separate statement it still fails.

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to the way that numbers are stored in Excel. If you round the subtraction or use TRUE as the last argument in the outer lookup, the formulas seem to work. I changed V2 to A2 for sake of the screenshot.

=VLOOKUP(ROUND(VLOOKUP(A2,Praise,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(D2,Praise,2,FALSE),1),Progress,2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,Praise,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(D2,Praise,2,FALSE),Progress,2,TRUE)

[image]

But there are combinations where the subtraction of the VLookup does not have an exact match in the Progress table, for example 2+ returns 2.8 and 1- returns 1.2. The subtraction result is 1.6 and a Vlookup with FALSE on the Progress table will return an error, while the vlookup with TRUE as the last parameter will return the next smallest match.

So check your V2 and D2 cells for combinations that are not found, and determine if you can get away with rounding or if you need to use TRUE in the outer lookup.

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your post. I had already tried that without success, and have just tried again and it still hasn't worked. That said I have already come up with a working solution, which actually uses the ROUND function as you suggest. My solution was to use this formula instead. =IF(Z2=0,"N/A",ROUND((VLOOKUP(V2,PRAISe,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(D2,PRAISe,2,FALSE))/0.3,0)) This works were VLOOKUP fails although why it works for you, and doesn't work for me is beyond me! Thanks anyway for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing some parenthesis in there to make it clear to the formulas the order of operations you intend?

```
=VLOOKUP((VLOOKUP(V2,PRAISe,2,FALSE))-(VLOOKUP(D2,PRAISe,2,FALSE)),Progress,2,FALSE)
```